GFCI could red light burn out when unused?
So i know the title is a bit vague, the thing i am asking about isn't really title sized.
Basically i just witnessed a GFCI outlet with nothing plugged in have the red light blink once. I then just stood there and watched it for a couple minutes and it did not blink again.
Extra detail is that there was no sounds made, and the green light was and is still on.
So i decided to press test and it does POP like normal for a GFCI and the green light turns off. HOWEVER, the red light did not turn on. Test button stayed pushed.
When pressing reset the grenn light comes back on.
This is an outlet we dont use often and hasn't been used in a couple weeks.
The green and red light are on different sides of the outlet buttons, and i have not seen that outlet be tripped.
I also tried to check for any IR light incase it is a hidden camera outlet.
Does anyone know what is going on?

I take it the red light blinked from "ON" to "OFF" to "ON" again?

problem with intermittent wiring somewhere

@ThreePhaseEel yes, it flashed on for a moment while i happened to be looking in the general direction, but only a single flash of the light, i waited for a bit to see if it would flash again, but it did not. And then i tried hitting test where the green led turned off when the test 'tripped' it. But the red light did not turn on. I hit reset and the green came back on.

@DIY75 i do know that the local power is a bit strange, we do live in a rental with less than desirable landlord quality, but i wasn't sure if this was a notice of anything or not since i don't know of anything that would have made a change to any active electrical use or anything at the time, i was the only one home and wasn't interacting with any electronics at the time. Apart from a weird light inside a closet there arent any concerning things But the streetlight outside does randomly fluctuate like a child with a dimmer switch, while the bulb also flickers like a dying tube light bulb.

You probably have a "self testing" GFCI.  They are not uncommon.  The red light blinks when going through the test process. It is done internally and does not interrupt the power through the outlet.

@RMDman see i did not know that could be a thing. Still confused as to why it wouldn't light up when manually tripped, but that could explain that.

@DIY75 yeah i thought of that while i was making that comment but due my work hours i have not been able to contact them since making that comment. Funny thing is light on the other side of us doesn't do that.

Look up the instructions for the particular model of GFCI (they are not all the same) to determine what the light should be doing before you flip out about what it is doing, which is more than likely "exactly what it should do."

But the streetlight outside does randomly fluctuate like a child with a dimmer switch, while the bulb also flickers like a dying tube light bulb.
Call your electricity company and inform them about that.
They have to come and inspect the transformer.
